# How do I write out each of the values in arr, which is an array of strings, one item per line

Tags: javascript, html

Write the body of the following function that writes out each of the values in arr, which is an array of strings, one item per line.
          function writeValues( arr ) {}

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>
        
         </title>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         function val(arr);
          var arr = ['item1', 'item2'];
          var len = var.length;
          for (var i =0, i<len; i++) {
      
         document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = arr[i];
         }
       </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <p id="para"></p>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Tried this:

I expect array of strings, one item per line.

Comment: After fixing the syntax error... You're going to overwrite the content of `document.getElementById('para')` on each iteration.

Comment: which error? I don't understand(

Comment: There are a lot of syntax errors actually. 1. your function should look like `function val(arr){ }`. It doesn't end with a semicolon. 2. It's `arr.length;`, not `var.length`. 3. Your `for` has a `,` instead of a `;`. Should look like this: `for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){}`. And finally, you probably want `innerHTML += arr[i]` instead of `+ arr[i]`.

Comment: thank you!) I am a total noob(

Comment: still not working though(

Comment: probably because you never actually call the function?

Comment: How do I call it? I tried this val(arr); in the <script> section; but it did not work(

Comment: here is what I have at the moment:

Comment: function val(arr){
      var arr = ['item1', 'item2'];
      var len = arr.length;
      for (var i =0; i<len; i++) {
      document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = arr[i];
      }
    }
    val(arr);

Comment: Thank you everyone! Now I understand how it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, you have a syntax errors:**

Your function declaration of:

```
function val(arr);
```

is incorrect. A function declaration must look like:

```
function someName(){

}
```

In the configuration of your `for` loop:

```
for (var i =0, i<len; i++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
```

**You should always work with your browser's developer tools turned on (F12) and be on the Console tab. This is where errors are reported.**

---

After that, your issue is that your code inside the loop:

```
document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = arr[i];
```

Says to set the `.innerHTML` of the `para` element to `arr[i]`, so that's what happens every time the loop iterates. Instead of a new line, you just wind up overwriting the last value in `para`.

Instead, you can append an HTML break (`<br>`) along with the array data by using `+=` instead of `=`:

Additionally, your code doesn't include a call to invoke the function.

See additional comments inline below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="para"></p>
  <!-- If you place your script before the HTML elements that the script wants
       to access, those elements won't be found because the HTML parser hasn't
       encountered them yet. By placing your script just before the closing
       body tag, all the HTML element will have been parsed and accessible.
       
       Also, type="javascript" is not necessary on a script tag.
  -->
  <script>
     function val(arr){
       var len = arr.length;
       var output = ""; // This will hold the final output
       for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         // From a performance standpoint, it's a very bad idea to update the
         // document inside of a loop. The DOM heirarchy winds up being rebuilt
         // upon each iteration and the document encounters "reflow" and "repaint"
         // events.  Instead, build up a string within the loop:
         output += "<br>" + arr[i];
       }
       // And, when the loop is done, inject the string into the document all at once:
       document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = output;
     }
     
     // The array should be declared outside of the function so that it (or any other
     // array) can be passed into the function when it gets called.
     var arr = ['item1', 'item2'];
     
     val(arr);  // Invoke the function and pass it the array
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After commenting all the syntax errors I decided to fix them here and give a working example:

```js
// since you set arr as variable inside the function, you don't need to pass it as argument. 
// also the function doesn't end with a semicolon.
function val(){
    var arr = ['item1', 'item2'];

    // It's arr.length, not var.length
    var len = arr.length;
    
    // you put a , instead of a ;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        // use += instead of + to avoid replacing the existing value
        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML += arr[i];
    }
}
// call the function
val();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="para"></p>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't represent the document structure that the OP is using. If you were to replicate the OPs structure, you would see that there is another problem that you haven't addressed.